# Factorial loops with C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write a loop in C++ that calculates the factorial of a given input between (1 and 10 inclusive) then displays that factorial. The code only breaks when 0 is used as input. I have written the loop which does all these except that the only correct answer I get is the first input, all other successive iterations are wrong figures. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Kindly help.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
     int n,
     factorial = 1;
    
     do{
        cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): ";
        cin >> n;
        
        while (n < 0 || n > 10) {
            cout << "Error: " << n << " is outside the valid range \n";
            break;
        }
        if (n > 0 && n <= 10) {
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
                factorial *= i;
            }
            cout << "Factorial of " << n << " is " << factorial << endl;
        } else if (n==0){
            cout << "Good bye! \n";
            break;
        }
        n++;
    } while (n != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's output:

```bash
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 9
Factorial of 9 is 362880
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 8
Factorial of 8 is 1746419712
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 7
Factorial of 7 is 1567358976
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 6
Factorial of 6 is -1077936128
```

Here's desired output:

```bash
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 9
Factorial of 9 is 362880
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 8
Factorial of 8 is 40320
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 7
Factorial of 7 is 5040
Enter a number between 1 and 10 (or 0 to end program): 6
Factorial of 6 is 720
```

Comment: You don't reset the value of `factorial` to `1`, which you should right before calculating it.

Comment: Arguably the declaration of `factorial` should even be moved inside the loop body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you don't reset the temporary variable when going into 2nd and subsequent loop operations. The easiest way to remedy that is to move the variable definition lower, limiting its scope:

```
do {
    ...
    if (n > 0 && n <= 10) {
        int factorial = 1;            // <- here
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
            factorial *= i;
        }
        cout << "Factorial of " << n << " is " << factorial << endl;
    }
```

As it's not used past this point anyway. That being said, this code would benefit from some (pun not intended) refactoring. Ideally, `factorial` would be a function called in the input routine, like so:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) { // you can start with 2 here
        f *= i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Then it's impossible to use this function incorrectly from the outside, as the control for the temporary variable is encapsulated inside of the function.

Of course, it also makes the callsite much cleaner:

```
if (n > 0 && n <= 10) {
    cout << "Factorial of " << n << " is " << factorial(n) << endl;
}
```